# Private Docker Registry - what is the correct rootcertbundle?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to setup a private docker registry that is secured via the token method. The authentication server it is hitting is a private authentication server. I'm getting this error when trying to login: `level=info msg="unable to get token signing key"`

I am seeing a JWT token being generated and returned from the authentication server.

---

Docker Registry Config:

```
version: 0.1
log:
  accesslog:
    disabled: false
  level: info
  fields:
    service: registry
    environment: development
storage:
  delete:
    enabled: true
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
  host: https://127.0.0.1:5000
  addr: 0.0.0.0:5000
  debug:
    addr: 0.0.0.0:5001
  secret: notasecret123
  tls:
    certificate: /certs/registry.crt
    key: /certs/registry.key
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
auth:
  token:
    realm: https://localhost:3443/dockerauth
    service: https://localhost:5000
    issuer: https://localhost:3443
    rootcertbundle: /certs/registry.crt
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
```

---

JWT signing:

```
var i = 'https://localhost:3443';
var s = 'registry';
var a = 'https://localhost:5000';

var signOptions = {
  issuer: i,
  subject: s,
  audience: a,
  expiresIn: "1h",
  algorithm: "RS256"
};

var registryKey = fs.readFileSync('/app/bin/keys/registry.key');

var token = jwt.sign(payload, registryKey, signOptions);
```

I've tried creating a RSA public/private key to sign the JWT token and then set the rootcertbundle to the public RSA key, but I got an error indicating that I needed a PEM cert. So I created a PEM cert and got the same error I started out with.